# Purpose and limitations of HTML `pattern` & `type` attributes

Tags: html, forms, validation, frontend

I'm concerning about the consistency and responsibility of two HTML attributes related to forms:

- `pattern`: specifies a regular expression to match
- `type`: specifies the type of control to render

I think that the use of these two attributes can be redundant and sometimes even lead to inconsistencies.

Here is an example with redundancy:

```html
<input
      type="email"
      pattern=".+@.+" />
```

Here is an example with inconsistencies (because a value could not be both an email, and have 3 alphabetical characters):

```html
<input
      type="email"
      pattern="[A-Za-z]{3}" />
```

How would you interpret this? Am I missing something?

My interpretation may not be correct (or maybe one of these attributes is too much and could be removed from the HTML). Thank you for your insights.

Comment: just use `<input type="email" />` you don't need pattern for type email

Comment: `type="email"` already have a pattern. But if you want to use just `gmail` or some type of emails you should use pattern. If not don't use it.

Comment: Thanks for this feedback. If I understand correctly, email allows to define a global email pattern. And adding a pattern attribute allows to define a sub-pattern, right?

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: Look at this answer. He explained widely what I said .

Comment: Want to get even more confused? Consider the `inputmode=""`  attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I missing something?

Yes: the `pattern=""` attribute can be used **with** `<input type="email">` to place additional restrictions on whatever e-mail address is provided by the user.

For example, supposing Google's GMail's settings pages have an `<input type="email">` to allow users to specify another Gmail user for mailbox delegation or send them an internal GMail exclusive birthday e-card or something equally silly - in which case they'd use a `pattern=""` that only accepts known Google-owned GMail domain-names, i.e.:

```html
<input type="email" pattern=".*?@gmail\.(com|de|co\.uk)$" title="Google-owned Gmail domain-names only." />
```

BTW, [the HTML specs recommend](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#the-pattern-attribute) that whenever `pattern=""` is used, that `title=""` is also supplied which explains the restrictions to the end-user:

> When a control has a `pattern` attribute, the `title` attribute, if used, must describe the pattern. Additional information could also be included, so long as it assists the user in filling in the control. Otherwise, assistive technology would be impaired.